# Unable to get information from a PKCS certificate

Tags: certificates, pkcs12, pem, pfx

I sniffed the communication between the client and the server using Wireshark, and I found out that during the handshake session, the client sends its certificate to the server.

I've managed to get the client's certificate, which is a PKCS12 formatted certificate and it looks like this:

`MIIQuQIBAzCCEH8GCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCEHAEghBsMIIQaDCCCx8GCSqGSIb3DQEHBqCCCxAwggsMAgEAMIILBQYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCiqGSIb3DQEMAQYwDgQIYreCShA7AXACAggAgIIK2G6f/joD/1VqmZGehnd4f6UQ89fDrRUJ1tugG3ncL6ewz8iD/viVbdDtYD2+CYQaXAu2jx4ePRw9ohippdK3pQLPPDzjzN7p4RmmsdCc3F8lVEmVkDq2IRzB1BSmZ3HK6PU5v5BvUQmIqZpijUiLCLdn7dKNTyvjFFKDfGS0oy5JVYr+O5WS1CqxfafDtwrX+iCiHMzDulGYVldb9+FHV8SMKkiiwjszih3+hgo+S6DVa3Cyfir3KEa9G2MBh2VkeQgCQdw893WAyFbIwHdB9QWWkwSWk4FGCtXP4gZ0Vjprv0tRydxnAcxpish5b5vmG0uMtguRC2criPAyFhW1NlT2TqzlX/mJW+shdh2FRvSyGlWqzcPdcT8Uks8BnZHpYOZVP9LbYVnO0X7bEAnNw6lsmbL4jxPJhAXGXX16vaXcCWLF+s64qFG6j/Jp61Vf6MxJWiqaC2AWLIVfdh9FJjQlvKtoX04uK9abYdBEvJ/J3u+/YIO7EIPiVwet1C23PRahybAQuGIXXHkk23rSDQ2AaIwnNBCBmW+mv2RuraS5KOm7Lk/9a9jWEWbjTYIMYSiy0PUFjhiZjjf3F1E4OqHGhbmCn3uhiYBGUXLRD8D33R9kMpzg1CAKq5ZOOyMkcNy2TWiWFB0ykQNuaPoOaoiXtsJiGEM/9ejhFQzOB28GiE3DG7xRfOb/BQTgjPzzAtfs1yXalzWu9CgguVZ/7/wL9sQVO29BWYwZQvbizEGczmPcHnzK4ft81bK1Ap4jZDvqSEfOBbH6j2BNw1d9hPUF/kjaccm/2jKkJTG4zQSz7RzxNs3w+QrYryc5sx8sQgcnYyGemirizHoNahbQU9RIzjP3lE0IjTuYl//DVXlVMXMu6JuLGwlC1F5wZ108NH1gUBC/Hepz8PXbwqB+exuSFNO51Mfg8kPTekO7wMTJK6OVBFkHi5QQLiL1PZSTtD4ypfL8BA/BFpm8A5N6ERCIwK5h8AOFdUO58iYeH98lSdppbwEQL7cMsSFczvBMJgiSfcflmPR1/mDEJtC9lqXt4pXhxbLSwMLB/CKaAMKBR6O3Ej6KVOsH2gOt2xGSHW08EURLXBLkvaFEpFi7JYg+N9UAWfS9eCNiLD6KKPCf1eBtJXfN3AR/n8/qouhOeub+MEHXNIaUoBpwaH+68ezDh7EAId9ytZXkiDWO9XMJYvfDIcJHoAKSjEYpnMjr3C9FbUpMDm4Bzu2eDOPR5B9T3oXH+HUDlSn6wERxNd79FgWuyUljZ2kQXIPLlKEgcCulAszHQeLEYgh/vbnwj/4lZ+LNehI6qyAphfEr1WOSfbVVGrZe0ekUDHi0hEifYm3sVwoiJHDE4Z0Qa+xHmGohVPrlvELNhcG7K1+Hd+MuNgTNAwxj40ix3qGQKEDfX
.........`

This is all I've got.

Also, I have the password used to secure the certificate, but I can't get any information out of it. So I've tried the extensions `.p12` and `.pfx` in the file containing my certificate, and I've tried to convert the `PEM format` using `openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.cer -nodes`; This didn't work!

I've also used the header/footer : ----BEGIN PKCS12-----/-----END PKCS----- and I still can't convert it to pem.

Is there anything else I can try? Thank you.

Comment: I believe, this is not a PFX, it is public X.509 certificate.

Comment: @Crypt32 what made you think this? The name of the function that gets me this certificate is `getCplusPKCS12Cert()` (java)

Comment: because only public part of certificate (in PKCS#7 format) is sent to server during mutual TLS negotiation. It is not PFX (PKCS#12).

Comment: @Crypt32 Thanks for your response. But can you please tell me how can you so 
sure that it's PKCS7 and not PKCS12?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2: `The certificate type MUST be X.509v3, unless explicitly negotiated otherwise (e.g., [TLSPGP]).`. Though, it is not a pure PKCS#7, it is a `SEQUENCE` which is ordered (rather unordered `SET`). Anyway, it is not PKCS#12.